# Is there a way to retain a worksheet when splitting multiple worksheets to workbooks? ie. like a frontpage/summary sheet

Tags: excel, vba, split

I have managed to split a workbook containing multiple worksheets with varying location data to separate workbooks based on a value in a column (geographical reference) which works great. However I have a front sheet that helps to refine the data. is there a way to copy this worksheet over to the split out workbooks whilst it's splitting out?

Otherwise is there another separate macro i could use to add the sheet into the workbooks post split?

The code below is a quick one I've used before for separating to workbook and emailing, I've simply disabled the email aspect of it.

```
Sub Split_To_Workbook_and_Email()
'Working in 2013/2016
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DateString As String
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim myOutlook As Object
    Dim myMailItem As Object
    Dim mySubject As String
    Dim myPath As String
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'Prompt for Email Subject

    Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Copy every sheet from the workbook with this macro
    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
    'Create new folder to save the new files in
    DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
    FolderName = "File Name" & Sourcewb.Name & " " & DateString
    MkDir FolderName
    'Copy every visible sheet to a new workbook
    For Each sh In Sourcewb.Worksheets
        'If the sheet is visible then copy it to a new workbook
        If sh.Visible = -1 Then
            sh.Copy
            'Set Destwb to the new workbook
            Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook
            'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
            With Destwb
                If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                    'You use Excel 97-2003
                    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
                Else
                    'You use Excel 2007-2016
                    If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
                        MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
                        GoTo GoToNextSheet
                    Else
                        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                    End If
                End If
            End With
            'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
            If Destwb.Sheets(1).ProtectContents = False Then
                With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
                    .Cells.Copy
                    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .Cells(1).Select
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
            'Save the new workbook, email it, and close it

        With Destwb
                .SaveAs FolderName _
                      & "\" & Destwb.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr, _
                        FileFormat:=FileFormatNum, _
                        Password:="AreaXXX", _
                        WriteResPassword:=""

            End With
            myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
            With Destwb
                .Close False
            End With

        End If
GoToNextSheet:
    Next sh
    MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You appear to be setting Sourcewb  and Destwb both to the ActiveWorkbook. Is this right? I would have thought you should be creating new workbooks for each instance of the loop.

Comment: Hi Chris, I honestly hadn't even noticed. As i said, it's a code I've used before that worked for the initial purpose of converting the multiple worksheets to workbooks. Would you advise i start from scratch?

Comment: Oh, I see where you're coming from. The .copy operation copies the active sheet to a new workbook, and sets that workbook as active. Makes sense now. However I tend to find that ActiveWorkbook is unreliable. I'll write a better version for you...

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, I really appreciate your time and effort! Do you know of a way to carry over a front sheet as stipulated in the original question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub SheetsToNewWorkbook()
    Dim SourceWB As Workbook, DestWB As Workbook
    Dim FrontPage As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
    Set SourceWB = ThisWorkbook ' Or whatever Workbook object your source is
    Set FrontPage = SourceWB.Sheets("NameOfYourSummarySheet") ' Set the name
    Dim SheetsInNewWorkbook As Long ' Variable to store the current setting
    SheetsInNewWorkbook = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook
    ' Create new folder to save the new files in
    Dim DateString As String, FolderName As String
    DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
    FolderName = "File Name" & SourceWB.Name & " " & DateString ' You might want to change these
    MkDir FolderName ' This will cause an error if the dir already exists
    ' Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    Dim FileExtStr As String, FileFormatNum As Long
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143 ' Excel 97-2003
    Else
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51 'Excel 2007-2016
    End If
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    End With
    '
    For Each sht In SourceWB.Worksheets
        If sht.Visible And (Not sht.Name = FrontPage.Name) Then
            Set DestWB = Workbooks.Add ' Creates a new workbook with only 1 sheet
            sht.Copy After:=DestWB.Sheets(1) 'Copy the sheet in question
            DestWB.Sheets(1).Delete ' Delete the default "Sheet1" which was created in the new workbook
            FrontPage.Copy Before:=DestWB.Sheets(1) ' Now copy the FrontPage
            ' And save & close the destination workbook:
            With DestWB
                .SaveAs FolderName & "\" & sht.Name & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum, Password:="AreaXXX", WriteResPassword:=""
                .Close False
            End With
        End If
    Next sht
CLEAN_UP:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .SheetsInNewWorkbook = SheetsInNewWorkbook
    End With
End Sub
```

I haven't included the completion message, or conversion to values etc: just a robust code for copying sheets to a new workbook, and then copying across the front page also.

Comment: Managed to sort the Summary sheet pulling through, just dealing with Run-time Error '1004': File could not be accessed. sat in the password protection  part of the code. any thoughts?

Comment: Got it working! just re-pasted the password segment (Which looks the same but hey ho!) and it's kicked in. Thank you so much for your help Chris! hope you have a fantastic 2019!